# updating a kernel without recompiling the whole kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm working in a protocol modification project in Linux kernel.

Each time i edit even one word in the source code, I need to make, compile and load all the modules and reboot my system to check the modification which takes more than 10 minutes.

Is there any way to add the modified code to the specific kernel module with out recompiling the whole kernel and/or without rebooting?

the code i'm using to recompile the whole kernel is

```
make
make modules_install
make install
reboot
```

***Updated: With @askb's answer***

I tried @askb's answer and getting the following error.

```
[@ 3.16.1]# make scripts && make prepare
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
[@ 3.16.1]# make ./net/sctp/
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC [M]  net/sctp/output.o
  LD [M]  net/sctp/sctp.o
  LD [M]  net/sctp/sctp_probe.o
[@ 3.16.1]# cd ./net/sctp/
[@ sctp]# insmod sctp
insmod: ERROR: could not load module sctp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If your Code is part of loadable module, then no need to compile the kernel, just use "make modules_install" and "insmod" to test that only feature in the kernel. Also note that If you modify a part of static kernel source code, then you need to follow the above mentioned steps

Comment: Its best to add in your description if the module you are working on it a part of the existing kernel code base or something new you are coding.

Comment: @askb it's a part of the existing kernel code base.

Comment: @SantoshA how to know if the module is loadable or not? I'm modifying the SCTP module.

Comment: @RatDon then the steps provide should help, To check if your module is loaded module or not, check the directory for .ko (kernel object) file. Its easier to use `make menuconfig`. Pressing <Y> includes include the module code as a part of the kernel, <N> excludes, <M> modularizes, i.e creates a separate .ko.

Comment: @askb so u r saying <M> and <Y> both can work fine for all the modules?

Comment: @Ratdon, yes - it depends on whether you want to build the functionality as a part of you kernel image (vmlinux) or a loadable module, which can be loaded once the kernel is booted.

Comment: @askb so the loadable module will not be a part of the vmlinux and after the kernel is booted we have to load it using insmod. right??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don’t need to rebuild the complete kernel code base, if its only a module which needs to be modified. All you need to do would be prepare the kernel kconfig and makefile scripts once, build the kernel module and load and unload it, with the following steps.

```
make menuconfig
make scripts && make prepare
make ./path/to/module/dir
cd ./path/to/module/dir
insmod <module name>
rmmod <module name>
```

Alternatively, if you are looking at ways to test, reboot and/or upgrade the modified kernel without rebooting, try using [kexec](http://korovamilky.tumblr.com/post/16460518079/running-new-linux-kernel-without-rebooting) or [ksplice](https://www.ksplice.com/)

Comment: i tried this one and not succeeding. updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Ratdon - From the output updated, it looks like the `sctp` is not enabled to the compiled as a kernel module (should be `M`) in the .config file. Try to change it to compile as module using `make menuconfig`.

Comment: I did that. after that only it's showing the above error. i guess somehow `make` is not creating the kernel object files for SCTP.

Comment: you may have skipped `make scripts && make prepare` after changing the .config and directly run `make <path/to/dir>`

Comment: no i've not skipped. You can check my code in the question. i was going through the makefile of SCTP and there is no rule to create the kernel object files. so i'm trying to add some rules for that.

Comment: i've made the makefile of sctp to create the kernel object files. but now also i'm not able to modify and check the module during runtime.

Comment: I tried `insmod sctp.ko`. but it said `unable to load. file already exists`. i tried `insmod sctp_probe.ko` and it loaded successfully. but i guess i need to load both the kernel object files. `rmmod sctp` is saying `module in use`.

Comment: Check the ref count of the loaded module, ex: there could be come open fd's which are be referrenced by some user space application. Therefore, you can seldom rmmod.

Comment: the only application that uses SCTP is `iperf` and i'm killing it using `pkill -9 iperf`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some IDE such as Eclipse. So you would not have to build whole project each time and modify the make files as you need.

Thus you would only overhead would be rebooting the physical/virtual machine.

Comment: will try and inform the status.